# Как поменять значок "гамбургера" программно?

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer, android-navigation-view

Как поменять программно значок "гамбургера"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
mDrawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(yourdrawableres);
```

Или так:

```
 toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu);
```